# Angular. How to get access of ng-repeat item scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="item in [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5}]"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope){
  //how to get access to child scope of element with id===3?
  for(var i = 0,len = $('span').length;i<len;i++){
    if($('span').eq(i).scope().id === 3){
      //do something with scope of element with id===3
    }
  }
})
```

How to access this scope without DOM manipulations?

Comment: It's clearly a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you really want to do?

Comment: You never do any DOM manipulation inside of a controller. What you're trying to do you would do inside the repeater itself inside of your view. Inside of your `<span>` you can do an `ng-if="item.id === 3"` to do something specific for that one

Answer (score 1):

Define the array in the controller. And then you can acces is easily:

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="item in MyList"></span>
</div>

.controller('someCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.MyList =  [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5}]

  $scope.Mylist[2]...
})
```

Comment: I'm asking about access of scope, not the object

Comment: You access the scope through its data and functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, you can easily get to by doing it inside of the repeater.

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="item in [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5}]">

        <!-- do whatever you want -->

        <!-- do something specific if it's id === 3 -->
        <span ng-if="item.id === 3">
            <strong>{{ item.id }}</strong> 
        </span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Also, you never do DOM manipulation (Javascript / jQuery / whatever) inside of a controller / service / factory. Only inside **directives**, even though try to keep it minimal.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclamer:** don't use this code in real applications!

Okay this is terrible thing to do, but for the sake of academic interest I'm going to post the answer of how you can get hold of child scope from controller.

Since `ngRepeat` creates child scopes of the current `$scope` for every rendered item, all you need to do is read `$$childHead` (`$first` item) and from there check `$$nextSibling` scopes until you find necessary scope object.

One caveat: you need to run object search during *next* digest cycle, since there is nothing rendered yet during the digest controller is executed in. So you can use `$timeout` service for this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var childScope = $scope.$$childHead;

    while (childScope = childScope.$$nextSibling) {
        if (childScope.item.id === 3) {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(childScope);
    alert(JSON.stringify(childScope.item));
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KLtTSnrS8lIEejMhKuby?p=preview